# Installing lodash as a different variable (not _) for compatibility purposes

Tags: lodash

Is it possible to install lodash as a different variable name, not the standard `_`? I know you could actually change the `lodash.js` file, but I would like to avoid having to do this everytime I need to upgrade the version.

The reason for this is that I have a system which uses an old version of underscore already, and I cannot replace it due to compatibility. I would like to install the latest lodash using say double underscore (`__`), and then be able to get the best of both worlds.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [_.noConflict()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#noConflict)

Put this in your code:

```
var __ = _.noConflict();
```

now you can use the double underscore to refer to lodash.